# SwiftUI - TabView - PageView Fullscreen Problem

Tags: swiftui, border, fullscreen, tabview, pageviews

I hope somebody can help me.

I want to make a page wise scrolling through unique designed Views.(in .swift-Files)
Nearly everything worked like intended with the Tabview.
I do not get a clean fullscreen for my Views.

First problem:
When I swipe on my first page to the right or on my last Page to the left I get shown the background of my TabView in shiny white.
[Shiny TabView Background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TViC.png)
I tried something with an infinite frame in a SeiteX.View but found only other Problems and nothing I intended.

Next problem:
I have to make my TabView to ignore the safe areas. Otherwise I get
[TabView with safeareas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFLyc.png)
But when I do this also my Views inside the TabView ignore the safe areas too.
Look at the tale of the Airplane.
[Inner Views ignoring the safe areas too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMf83.png)
Can I avoid this?

My app.swift

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
                ZStack {
                    TabView {
                        Seite1()
                        Seite2()
                        Seite3()
                    }
                    .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never)) //ohne Index-Punkte
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My .swift-File for one example Page

```
import SwiftUI

struct Seite2: View {
    var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                Color.black.ignoresSafeArea()
                
                HStack(spacing: 50){
                    Image("Fly2")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                    Text("Test-Text dfvfb vtgbhzbnzh tbhbzhbnzh bzhzhb zbzhbzhbn zhbzhnbz zbzhbnznb ztbzhnbzjn zbz zhbbn zbnzn ")
                        .font(.largeTitle)

                }
                .padding()

            }
        }
    }

struct Seite2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Seite1()
    }
}
```

What I tried:
putting the ignore safearea at nearly every possible position.
frames with georeader and infinity in the HStack and ZStack.
Trying .overlay in ZStack.
A Backgroundlayer with ZStack in many places.

What I hope to get:
I need as simple as possible clean SwiftUI solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all theses `ZStack`. Just give your `TabView` a `.background` and IN the background `.ignoresSafeArea`.

So SwiftUI layouts all elements respecting the safe areas, except for the color in the background.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
             TabView {
                 Seite(page: 1)
                 Seite(page: 2)
                 Seite(page: 3)
             }
             .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
             .background(Color.teal.ignoresSafeArea()) // here
    }
}

struct Seite: View {
    let page: Int
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 50){
            Image("plane\(page)")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
            Text("Test-Text dfvfb vtgbhzbnzh tbhbzhbnzh bzhzhb zbzhbzhbn zhbzhnbz zbzhbnznb ztbzhnbzjn zbz zhbbn zbnzn ")
                .font(.largeTitle)
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying. This solution only works when the views in the tabview have no own background. That is somethings i want. Also the boxy effect around the tabview is something i want to avoid. Ps: I like your plane ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Second try after new information :).
Now it has 2 backgrounds, one general black one, and one individual color for the views.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
             TabView {
                 Seite(page: 1)
                 Seite(page: 2)
                 Seite(page: 3)
             }
             .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
             .ignoresSafeArea()
             .background(Color.black.ignoresSafeArea()) // general black background
    }
}

struct Seite: View {
    
    let colors: [Color] = [.blue, .green, .yellow, .orange, .red, .teal, .mint]
    
    let page: Int
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 50){
            Image("plane\(page)")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
            Text("Test-Text dfvfb vtgbhzbnzh tbhbzhbnzh bzhzhb zbzhbzhbn zhbzhnbz zbzhbnznb ztbzhnbzjn zbz zhbbn zbnzn ")
                .font(.largeTitle)
            
        }
//        .border(.red, width: 2) // to show inner frame
        .padding()
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(colors.randomElement()!.ignoresSafeArea()) // individual view background

    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you!
Looks like a way for me.
I was still thinking about swapping the now black background on yours for an image with a logo or something. Then this effect has even an added value.

Comment: Today I tested the Code 1:1. There is still the Problem, that the text or the images are  behind the magic Island.